# shared vimrc on two machines; only run command for one of them

Tags: vimrc, git

I use git to share my vimrc across multiple machines. 
But now I have some commands which I only want on one machine. Namely, this
line:
`au! redhat BufReadPost`
(derived from this very helpful answer!
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59486/disable-vi-from-going-to-the-last-visited-line-upon-file-opening)

Is there a way to load this line only for my linux machine? Or maybe put into a
second vimrc file which only exists/loads on linux? Or maybe another solution, so that I can keep using version control for the rest of my files but let this one command apply just for this one machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surround the config/code in question with a conditional based on an [environment variable](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-env).

If you're using Bash environments a good candidate is envvar `HOSTNAME` which will probably be unique (in a personal context, at least). In other environments there is usually a way to get this same information (e.g.  output of the *nix command `hostname` or envvar `COMPUTERNAME` on Windows). If you have a heterogeneous mix of machines then the best approach is probably to use the Vim function `hostname()` which provides a platform agnostic means of getting the information.<sup>1</sup>

For simplicity, we'll pretend we're all in on Bash. :) For the example you mentioned we'd just need to add something like...

```
 if $HOSTNAME == "foo"
     au! redhat BufReadPost ...
 endif
```

Of course, we can also extend this to multiple hosts and/or have default settings...

```
 if $HOSTNAME == "foo"
     " this config
 elseif $HOSTNAME == "bar"
     " that config
 else
     " default config
 endif
```

Before you set it up check availability with `:echo $HOSTNAME`.

If you want to look for alternatives you could run `:!printenv` or `:!env` or whatever your system's equivalent command is. In the unlikely event that you can't find an existing envvar that will work then make something up! Choose a variable name not currently in use and on the machine(s) you want to isolate put (assuming Bash, again) `export MYSPECIALVAR=uniquevalue` in your *.profile*, *.bash_profile*, *.bashrc* or whatever makes the most sense for your environment.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Thanks to @Achilleas for spurring me to expand/improve this section.</sub>

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: The availability of `$HOSTNAME` in the environment depends on the system or shell and maybe even other factors.  It looks like vim has a [`hostname()` function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#hostname()) for this, which should be more universally available.

Comment: @Achilleas A good point. Note updated answer. Cheers.